# Deleting running files

Tags: delete-file, antivirus, mcafee

When I used the latest version of McAfee Antivirus, I noticed that the shred feature can delete running files and then asks you to restart your computer. Do anyone know how does it delete running files without closing them?

Comment: I'm marking this as off-topic as off-site resource is requested. The question also seems to be outside the purview of StackOverflow.

Comment: i'm sorry. i'm new to this website

Comment: i don't even know how to comment on your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on the OS and file system types. On Linux and Unix like, deleting a file a just removing an entry from a folder. The file is actually deleted on last close if no folder entry points to it. So you can safely delete a file even if it is opened in another process.

On Windows the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file

Usual tricks include:

- try to close all processes having handles on that file. For an executable it generally means terminating all its instances
- mark the file for deletion on next reboot. As you say that McAfee asks to reboot the computer it likely uses that option. The `MoveFileEx` WINAPI function has provision for that. Extracts from [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasize mine)

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI MoveFileEx(
>   _In_     LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
>   _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
>   _In_     DWORD   dwFlags
> );
> ```
>
> ... 
> lpNewFileName [in, optional]
>       The new name of the file or directory on the local computer.
> ...
>       **If dwFlags specifies MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT and lpNewFileName is NULL, MoveFileEx registers the lpExistingFileName file to be deleted when the system restarts**.